# How is the orientation of an electromagnetic wave determined?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, polarization

I was looking up for how polarisers work, I understood mostly everything except the part that explains that the polariser filters everything except light that is in a certain orientation.

Here are my questions. How do waves have different orientation except being either vertical or horizantal? What determines the orientation and how does that affect in absorption of the wave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plane polarized light the orientation of the electric oscillation is ultimately a quantum effect, but I think it's a reasonably accurate classical approximation to say that it is determined by the ability of solid matter interacting with light to support electric vibrations (electron motions) preferably in a single direction. For light reflected at an angle from a smooth surface (e.g. a road at dawn as you are driving), the preferred direction for the electric oscillation turns out to be perpendicular to the surface. So, "horizontal" polarized light turns out to have an electrical oscillation that is vertical, which is not exactly intuitive.